# When the Cartesian product of two graphs is edge transitive?

Tags: graph-theory

A graph $G$  is said to be edge transitive provided that, for any two edges $f$ and $g$  in $G$ , there is an automorphism of $G$  sending $f$  to $g$.

Answer (score 2):

Any graph has a unique decomposition as a Cartesian product of "prime" graphs (where a graph is prime if cannot be expressed as a proper Cartesian product).
Hence any graph can be expressed as product of pairwise coprime Cartesian powers.
The automorphism group of the product of coprime graphs is the Cartesian product of its factors. The automorphism group of the $k$-th power of a graph is the wreath product of its automorphism group by $\mathrm{Sym}(k)$. The standard proofs go by defining an equivalence relation on edges, which is group invariant. One consequence of all this is that a Cartesian product is edge transitive if and only if it factors are.

The standard source for this stuff is "Handbook of Product Graphs" by Hammack, Imrich and Klavzar.

Answer (score 0):

For any vertex and edge-transitive graph $G$, the $n^{th}$ Cartesian
power $G^{\times ,\, n}$ is vertex- and edge-transitive.

**Imrich, W. Embedding Graphs into Cartesian Products. Ann. N.Y. Acad.
Sci. 1989, 576, 266-274.